# CSS responsive web: display 2 ul li elements in one line (into each other)

Tags: html, css, html-lists, responsive-design

If there is no space to display these two lists next to eachother, can i push their elements in "one" list?

For example:

```
   <ul>
     <li>A1</li>
     <li>A2</li>
     <li>A3</li>
  </ul>
   <ul>
     <li>B1</li>
     <li>B2</li>
     <li>B3</li>
  </ul>
```

should be like that:

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3
```

Comment: I would reconsider why you're using two lists for A and B, when it appears that A1 and B1 are permanently associated with each other. I'd consider using a table or simply, creating a list such that `<li>A1</li> <li>B1</li>` always appear in that way, and deal with the styling in the different views.

Comment: It's not possible through CSS alone, because with the intercalating `<li>` that you want to achieve requires rewriting and rearranging the elements.

Alternatively, you can concatenate them into a single parent `<ul>` element. When the screen gets wide enough you display the odd and even `<li>` elements (using `nth-child([:odd|:even]`) separately (by float or positioning)

Comment: Impossible to do in css unless you can predict/hardcode the heights of the lists items and put the two of them in a container. In which case it would be peanuts. see @xpy's  answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I came up with:

```
    ul,li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }
    ul {
        position:absolute;
    }
    li {
        margin-bottom:1.2em;
    }
    ul+ul{
        margin-top:1.2em;
    }
```